# How to make an ordered list item in PHPWord?

Tags: php, phpword

Consider the layout:

1. will.i.am
2. Will Smith

   - Jaden Smith
3. Will Ferrell

The 1<sup>st</sup> level is ordered (not bulleted), the 2<sup>nd</sup> level could be anything.

Using the [`addListItem()`](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/elements.html#lists), **how to make an ordered list item in PHPWord?**

Answer (score 2):

Per the documentation that you linked, the fourth parameter of `addListItem()` is `$listStyle`, the value of which is taken from [these constants](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/master/src/PhpWord/Style/ListItem.php#L31-L36) defined in `PHPWord\Style\ListItem`. In your case, I'm assuming you want either `TYPE_NUMBER` or `TYPE_NUMBER_NESTED`.

Comment: I tried `7` `8` and `9`. All still returned bullets, not a list.

Comment: Ah, it may be due to [this change](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/072c3bfdb327f6984b8bb378b08f83ae2293a708/src/PhpWord/Style/ListItem.php#L25-L27).

Toward the end of [this section](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/elements.html#lists), under "Advanced usage," there's an example of using numbering levels. That includes a related link to another area of the documentation. Have you also tried this?